# How to order bean fields by name using Intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to order bean fields (not methods) by name using Intellij idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Arrangement`, you will see a set of rules. If you click the pencil symbol on the right, you can edit the rule, including the order:

[image]